# Using async keyword in method signature to return a Task in Web Api endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task

If I wanted to write a non-blocking web api action by returning a `Task` object, I could do it with or without using the `async` keyword as such:

#### Using async

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    Func<HttpResponseMessage> slowCall = () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello world");
    };

    var task = Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(slowCall);
    return await task;
}
```

#### Without using async

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    Func<HttpResponseMessage> slowCall = () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello world");
    };

    var task = Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(slowCall);
    return task;
}
```

They both work properly. However, every example I've seen (online and in books) on writing a web api action that returns a `Task` uses the `async` keyword. Granted, I understand that gives you more flexibility as it allows you to control what you want to "await" on and what not. But assuming your functionality could be effectively handled either way,

- Is there any advantage to using one approach vs the other?
- Should I always use the async keyword (and if so why)?
- Or is it irrelevant?

Comment: `async` is useful if you want to do anything more complicated than your current code.

Comment: I know this is just example code, but I must point out that you shouldn't use `TaskFactory.StartNew` in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Stephen Why not? What do you suggest instead?

Comment: @rtorres: You should use naturally-asynchronous APIs. If you use `Task.Run` (or even worse, `StartNew`), you're just trading one thread for another. Let me turn the question around: what benefit do you get from `await` with `Task.Run` or `StartNew`?

Comment: @Stephen It's just an example in this case to simulate a long-running operation that can be run asynchronously (e.g., a network call). In real-life that'd probably be part of an API call. I didn't mean to communicate that this should be followed as an example to write your web api endpoints by any means.

Comment: @rtorres `Task.Delay` is a the usual example in such cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `async` keyword allows you to use an `await` in your method by creating a state machine. If you can manage returning an asynchronous task without using it you can go ahead and remove it because it has some (very small) overhead. Keep in mind though that it's only useful in a few cases. Your `return await` is one of them.

Another difference is how exceptions are handled. If there's an exception in the synchronous part of the method and it's marked as `async` the exception will be stored in the returned task. Without the keyword the exception would be thrown regularly. For example in this case there's a big difference:

```
var task = Get(); // unhandled exception without async
try
{
    var result = await task; // handled exception with async
}
catch
{
}
```

My recommendation is to use the `async` keyword even when you don't absolutely need to*, because most developers don't understand the difference and the value in the optimization is mostly negligible.

---

<sup>* Unless you and your teammates *really* know what you're doing.</sup>

Comment: Interestingly enough, I ran some JMeter tests to compare both options and the "async" one performed faster (as measured by the average response time). Not sure why (I would have expected it to be slower because of the state machine overhead) ... I may have set up the tests incorrectly. In any case, considering performance is similar, the ability to debug (along with the extra flexibility to control awaitable functionality) is a good reason to prefer the async approach so I agree with your recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

There is one advantage to bypassing the `await` and returning the `Task` directly: performance. You won't allocate or process the state machine that goes with an `async` method. There are, however, some subtle differences when exceptions are involved.

In the async example, any exceptions thrown will be enclosed in a `Task`. This is generally what people assume will happen when they call a Task-returning method. In the sync example, exceptions will be thrown immediately upon invocation.

This will also have an effect on the exception's stack trace. In the async example, it will show `Get()`. In the sync example, it will show your anonymous delegate or worse, some internal crap in `Task.Factory.StartNew` with no actual reference to your actual code. This can result in being a little more difficult to debug.