# How to implement synchronous Task-returning method without warning CS1998?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

Take for example the following interface:

```
interface IOracle
{
    Task<string> GetAnswerAsync(string question);
}
```

Some implementations of this interface might use `async`/`await`. Others might not need to. For example, consider this simple toy implementation.

```
class SimpleOracle
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Lookup { get; set; }

    // Warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators
    // and will run synchonously.
    public async Task<string> GetAnswerAsync(string question)
    {
        string answer = Lookup[question];
        return answer;
    }
}
```

The compiler warning CS1998 of course makes sense. The usual suggestion is to [remove the `async` keyword and use `Task.FromResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13243975/1828879), but it misses a subtle issue.  What if the code throws an exception? Then that code transform changes the behavior of the method: the `async` version will wrap any exception in a `Task`; the non-`async` version will not, without an explict `try`-`catch`.

Leaving the `async` keyword works exactly as I want, but it produces a compiler warning, and I don't think suppressing those is wise.

How should I refactor my method implementation to not produce a compiler warning while also wrapping all exceptions with `Task` as any other `async` method would?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mechanical translation I use to convert from the `async` version that yields compiler warning CS1998 to a non-`async` version that behaves identically is as follows.

- Remove the `async` keyword.
- Wrap the entire existing method body with a `try`-`catch`.
- Define a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` called `tcs` before the `try`-`catch`.
- Replace all existing instances of `return <expr>;` with `tcs.SetResult(<expr>);` followed by `return tcs.Task;`.
- Define the `catch` block to call `tcs.SetException(e)` followed by `return tcs.Task;`.

For example:

```
public Task<string> GetAnswerAsync(string question)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    try
    {
        string answer = Lookup[question];
        tcs.SetResult(answer);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tcs.SetException(e);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

This can be expressed more generally by the following, although I don't know if it would be appropriate to actually introduce such a helper method into a codebase.

```
public static Task<T> AsyncPattern(Func<T> func)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    try
    {
        tcs.SetResult(func());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tcs.SetException(e);
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30852187/1768303) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21082631/1768303) for yet another option: `Task.RunSynchronously`. I personally like it more than `TaskCompletionSource` approach.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using .NET 4.6, you can use `Task.FromException` to handle the exception case, just as you use `FromResult` to handle the successful case:

```
public Task<string> GetAnswerAsync(string question)
{
    try
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Lookup[question]);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return Task.FromException<string>(e);
    }
}
```

If you're using .NET 4.5 then you'll need to write your own `FromException` method, but it's pretty trivial:

```
public static Task<T> FromException<T>(Exception e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    tcs.SetException(e);
    return tcs.Task;
}
public static Task FromException(Exception e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    tcs.SetException(e);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```