# Ignore async without await compilation warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a base controller with the following abstract method:

```
[HttpDelete]
public abstract Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id);
```

In one particular controller, I don't want to implement deletion, so the method looks like this:

```
public override async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, new NotSupportedException()));
}
```

Although the above code compiles, I get a warning:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Apart from ignoring the above warning, is there a better alternative (ie. changing the code above) so that this warning doesn't occur?

**EDIT**

I change the line to:

```
return await Task.Run(() => ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, new NotSupportedException())));
```

This removes the warning. However, is there a better solution?

Comment: If you don't want the delete action be to allowed, why are you deriving from it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Apart from ignoring the above warning, is there a better alternative
>   (ie. changing the code above) so that this warning doesn't occur?

The alternative is to remove the `async` modifier and use `Task.FromResult` to return a `Task<IHttpActionResult>`:

```
public override Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    return Task.FromResult<IHttpActionResult>(
                ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(
                                        HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed,
                                        new NotSupportedException())));
}
```

Comment: With the above answer, I get the following exception: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult>'`

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono change the code to `Task.FromResult<IHttpActionResult>(ResponseMessage(...));`

Answer (score 6):

While [Yuval's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30501187/885318) regarding removing the `async` completely is usually the prefered way to remove the warning, another *correct* answer that doesn't degrage performance is to `await` an already completed task.

`await` is roughly translated to checking whether the awaited task completed, if so continue on executing the rest of the method synchronously and if not add the rest as a continuation on that task.

```
private static readonly Task _completedTask = Task.FromResult(false);
public override async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    await _completedTask;
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, new NotSupportedException()));
}
```

In .Net 4.6 you can use the new `Task.CompletedTask` property instead of creating your own completed task.

This enables you to keep the method `async` and with it keep the [same error-handling semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205356/885318).

Comment: And then you create a new object of a hidden class, call methods on it that use that cached completed task, and then have that object garbage collected. I'm not talking about the task that the method is `await`ing, I'm talking about the task that it returns. Again, it's not a serious hit, but it's not true that it "doesn't degrade performance" either.

Comment: @JonHanna All options must return a new task.

Comment: @JonHanna but if you're refering to the state machine being generated by the async method, then it's being generated in the original code as well, so **there is no degradation**

Comment: @JonHanna moreover, that state machine is a struct, and only moves to the heap when you really suspend the method, which doesn't happen when the awaited task is completed. So **there's no allocation, no collection and no degradation**.

Comment: You're correct, there's no allocation. There is still more done than in Yuval's answer though, unless the methods involved get inlined.

Comment: @JonHanna again, there's no degradation over the *original code*.